# SQL query on many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a recipes website, where recipes and foods are stored in MySQL db. There is a many to many relationship between tables.

**Foods Table**

| FoodId | FoodName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Spaghetti |
| 2 | Fish |

**Ingredients Table**

| IngredientId | IngredientName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Lettuce |
| 2 | Milk |
| 3 | Pasta |
| 4 | Sauce |

**Foods-Ingredients Table**

| FoodId | IngredientId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| ... | ... |

The user want to get a list of foods he can make based on the ingredient he/she has. For example he has pasta and sauce.
So the input for the SQL Query will be a list :

```
[pasta, sauce]
```

The return should be also a string, in this case an array with one element :

```
[Spaghetti]
```

Is it possible to make this with 1 MySQL query and how?

Comment: Why do `Spaghatti` and `Fish` have the same `FoodId`?

Comment: Okay, I'm going to go ahead and reformat this entire post

Comment: @VirajShah Do you know the answer? :)

Comment: Yup. I'm writing my answer right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select not just foods that have the provided ingredients, but also foods that have *only* the provided ingredients.

In my DB Fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2sgrcERybJuZxFSrBco61Y/1

I have added "Creamy Spaghetti" which requires Milk, Pasta, and Sauce.  This gives us a test case where a recipe has both given ingredients, but requires other stuff.

The fiddle includes a copy of @Viraj Shah's answer (with corrected table names) to prove it doesn't work in this case.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT Foods.FoodName, FoodIngredients.FoodId, 
  COUNT(*) as Ingredients, 
  SUM(IF(IngredientName in ("pasta","sauce"), 1, 0)) as Available 
FROM FoodIngredients
  JOIN Foods ON (FoodIngredients.FoodId = Foods.FoodId)
  JOIN Ingredients ON (Ingredients.IngredientId = FoodIngredients.IngredientId)
GROUP BY Foods.FoodName, FoodIngredients.FoodId
HAVING Ingredients = Available;
```

Here, I count all the ingredients the dishes have as well as how many of them match one of our available ingredients.

I am making the assumption that there are no duplicate ingredients in the `FoodIngredients` table.  That would throw off the count if there were duplicates.  It would also be "wrong"; that field would be a foreign key in real life.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ do me a favor and check out this website, making sure to note its "Text to DDL" button.  I was able to paste in Viraj's edited SO table markup directly into that site to create the schema.  If you put the effort into creating a db fiddle link for your next SQL question , it will make it 1000% easier to answer your question.  I'm not affiliated with the site but I value it as a tool

Answer (score 1):

I am making the following assumptions:

1. You are using an undefined context (could be stored procedure, prepared statement, any MySQL context)
2. You don't mind executing multiple queries

```sql
SELECT f.FoodName 
    FROM Foods f 
    JOIN Foods_Ingredients fi
        ON f.FoodId = fi.FoodId 
    JOIN Ingredients i
        ON fi.IngredientId = i.IngredientId 
    WHERE i.IngredientName IN ('Pasta', 'Sauce') 
    GROUP BY f.FoodId 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.IngredientId) = 2
```

If you are writing this as a stored procedure that can be applied to any set of ingredients, then you would replace `('Pasta', 'Sauce')` with your data variable.

Comment: @Viray Snah Thank you. Is it working with multiple ingredients as well? For example the user enters 4  ( not 2 )  ingredients. He will still get back a list of foods which he can make?

Comment: That's not quite right. Since you're filtering ingredients that match your given list, any required ingredients that *don't match* the list are filtered out.  You've found all recipes that require both Pasta and Sauce, but you've also included recipes that need other stuff.  I'll put a Fiddle link in my answer.